# Efficient customization of Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question: Is there a more efficient way to customize elements when using Bootstrap? I find it tedious to have to target elements in such a specific way, ie:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav
.active a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-default
.navbar-nav li a:focus {
  background-color: #1A77FF;
}
```

I feel as though something like the following should do the trick, if I want all of my links to be styled the same way, but it doesn't override Bootstrap's default styles.

```
a:hover, a:focus {
  background-color: #1A77FF;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Bootstrap CSS code for anchors?

Comment: Note that, assuming you're a complete newbie, your css code must be read/linked after the bootstrap css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written in your custom CSS won't override Bootstrap's CSS for anchors because bootstrap's CSS will be more specific as they will have written a class into their anchors to give them the consistent Bootstrapped look and feel.

If you look on their documentation regarding buttons and links (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options), you can get a better understanding of how they style them and build from there - I can understand where you're coming from with these questions though, I've found that Codeacademy doesn't always explain these little quirks particularly well so I shall try and clarify it for you.

**Cascading** Style Sheets (CSS) operates on a basis of whichever rule is more specific in targeting an element will be processed.

If I was to have a page with two anchor tags on it and styling that targeted an element specifically, as follows:

```css
a {
  color: magenta;
  font-family: 'Comic-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

a.more_specific {
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Impact', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>

  <a href="#" alt="this can only be targeted by using a {}">Basic link</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="more_specific" alt="this can be targeted using a {} OR a.more_specific {}">More specific</a>
  
 </body>
```

You'll notice that the bottom link's styling, despite it still being an anchor, gets overridden by the more specific rule.

The way I tend to overcome the issue you're facing with Bootstrap's CSS is to add an id attribute to that element (or those elements if you're targeting more than one) which can then be used to override the styling from bootstrap.  This will maintain Bootstrap's specificity in the way that they target the elements but will enable you to effectively jump right to the end of that long chain of refinements, so if you give your anchor in the navbar an id of, say, "navbar-anchor" and then target that in your CSS, it will have the same effect as targeting it with the long chain of refining targets.

This is a much more sustainable way of doing it than simply using !important as suggested in the answer from the first provider.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know if you include the stylesheet after bootstap.css in which you have written the css code it will override the matching css in the bootstrap.css file but if bootstrap has used selectors along with tag then its difficult to do so.

!important is one way and 
2nd way is to extend the css code with the parent class,id or element so that it over rides the bootstap.css code which you already did.